# Add shared project jars in websphere shared library

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, websphere, shared-libraries

We can add project dependency jars (like spring jars, logging etc) in shared library, can we add shared project jars (like one that communicate with Database) in shared library?

**Scenario:**

I have these projects

1. WebApp
2. WebAppEAR
3. CommonDB

I am using `IBM Websphere server, hibernate, spring mvc`

I added all spring, hibernate jars including CommonDB.jar in Websphere shared library. WebApp Application is running successfully with spring controllers but when my application try to hit DB it throws exception.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException:
```

Actually WebApp  is not loading `<bean>` DataSource. DataSource class is located in CommonDB project.

When I include CommonDB.jar in Deployment assembly of EAR WebApp runs successfully and fetches data from DB.
I want to exclude CommonDB.jar from Deployment assembly and only want to add it in shared library.

Comment: Are you specifying your CommonDB.jar in your libraries.xml in your EAR file? I assume you have uploaded and configured the jar as a shared library via admin console or wsadmin script?

Comment: @Terrell Plotzki: CommonDB.jar is placed on local path. Its path is included in shared library. Its not uploaded.

Comment: Verify all your steps with this http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v6r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.websphere.nd.doc%2Finfo%2Fae%2Fae%2Ftcws_sharedlib_create.html

Comment: There's not enough information in that IllegalStateException to be able to offer much advice.  Is there no exception message or stack trace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding jars in shared library will work. Try figuring out which beans are not initialized and add them in Spring file to initialize. Also check other bean properties for dependency.